# React fragments break styling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Hi I am using Ant Design (not sure if that has anything to do with this weird behavior) and React Router in this example.

Using the following example totally breaks the styling of the app:

```
    {adminVisible && (
      <>
        <Item key={Routes.USER}>
          <Link to={Routes.USER}>Nový uživatel</Link>
        </Item>
        <Item key={Routes.CAR}>
          <Link to={Routes.CAR}>Nové vozidlo</Link>
        </Item>
        <Item key={Routes.REASON}>
          <Link to={Routes.REASON}>Nové účel jízdy</Link>
        </Item>
        <Item key={Routes.DESTINATION}>
          <Link to={Routes.DESTINATION}>Nová destinace</Link>
        </Item>
      </>
    )}
```

[image: wrong display]

But using the following work fine:

```
    {adminVisible && (
      <Item key={Routes.USER}>
        <Link to={Routes.USER}>Nový uživatel</Link>
      </Item>
    )}
    {adminVisible && (
      <Item key={Routes.CAR}>
        <Link to={Routes.CAR}>Nové vozidlo</Link>
      </Item>
    )}
    {adminVisible && (
      <Item key={Routes.REASON}>
        <Link to={Routes.REASON}>Nové účel jízdy</Link>
      </Item>
    )}
    {adminVisible && (
      <Item key={Routes.DESTINATION}>
        <Link to={Routes.DESTINATION}>Nová destinace</Link>
      </Item>
    )}
```

[image: right display]

The first example is much cleaner and I would like to use it but that doesnt work, meanwhile the second approach is not so pretty but works.

Could anyone explain to me why is this happening?

Thank you.

Comment: I prefer the first one as well. What do you mean by doesn't work. It seems fine to me. Both render the same HTML. We need a [mcve] to help you.

Comment: It breaks the styling. I will try to reproduce it in an example..

Comment: When you talk about the styling, you should share some CSS too. Yea, if you find it easier, you have [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)

Comment: Is the generated DOM tree different in both cases ?

Comment: @Treycos Yes, I think so.

Comment: Could you past/capture it and show both in your question ?

Comment: Did you try to use `Fragment` instead of <> syntax, just guessing.

Comment: @Treycos Pictures added.

Comment: @TariqN I tried.

Comment: The DOM tree is the HTML body generated...

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman it is not absolutely same my code but from the sandbox it is noticeable that it behaves differently in each case (if you switch comments around those parts) https://codesandbox.io/s/zk7wm675pp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<Fragment />` Does not actually add a DOM node, just a virtual DOM container. Unfortunately container components in ui frameworks deal with arrays of child components like in `<StyledMenu />` so the fragment will interfere with how this component works. It does stuff to the immediate child which in this case is a fragment and not an li so it applies classes to that and then it is stripped out of the dom because its a fragment.

There are a couple solutions, but none are particularly cleaner than your solution that works so I would just go with that.